# Django add many to many relationship from _meta.get_field

Tags: python, django, string, many-to-many, field

So I have the following

```
b = Brand.objects.create(**model_fields_and_values)
b.save()
```

and then I try to associate that entry with

```
b._meta.get_field("myfield").add(value3)
```

and I get the error `'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'add'`

How can I create an association using a string and not the field ???

I dont want to use `b.myfield.add(value3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) allows you to get an attribute using the attribute name:

```
getattr(b, 'myfield').add(value3)
```